# Where does function equal certain value

Tags: r, function

I have fitted a function to my data:

```
BCF.plot <- function(x) {
  vv[2] +((vv[3]/(2*(1-vv[4])))*(cos(x-vv[1])-vv[4]+abs(cos(x-vv[1])-vv[4])))
}
```

It is a baseline (b) cosine wave, i.e. a baseline with a cosine wave on top of it. Now I have a certain value on the Y-axis (dlmo_val) and I want to know which x value corresponds to it. I have tried something like this:

```
BCF.dlmo <- function(x, dlmo_val = 0) {
  vv[2] +((vv[3]/(2*(1-vv[4])))*(cos(x-vv[1])-vv[4]+abs(cos(x-vv[1])-vv[4])))-b-dlmo_val ## find point where function minus baseline & dlmo_val is 0
}

vv = c(2.3971780, 2.0666526, 11.1775231, 0.7870128)
b = 2.066653
H = 11.17752

dlmo_val = 0.4*H ## dlmo*peak height above baseline, H is result from optimisation
uniroot(BCF.dlmo, c(0.2617994, 6.021386), dlmo_val=dlmo_val)  ## lower & upper are min(x) and max(x)
```

However, uniroot tells me

```
"...values at end points not of opposite sign"
```

I am not really sure how to go about this. Any recommendations are more than welcome!

Comment: What are `b` and `H` equal to?

Comment: Ah sorry, forgot this and edited the post accordingly...

Comment: `curve(BCF.dlmo(x, dlmo_val = dlmo_val), from = 0.2617994, to = 6.021386)` shows that there are two points where your function equals zero- do you want to find both of them? Just one?

Comment: Thanks a ton! I am just looking for the first one..., the lower x-value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As described in this post](https://joftius.wordpress.com/2015/10/19/finding-multiple-roots-of-univariate-functions-in-r/), `uniroot()` is designed for finding only one zero in a function, while you have two zeroes. You could call it on a smaller interval:

```
uniroot(BCF.dlmo, c(0.2617994, 2.5), dlmo_val = dlmo_val)$root
# [1] 1.886079
```

As that post describes, you can instead use the `unitroot.all` function in the [rootSolve package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rootSolve/index.html) to find both zeroes:

```
library(rootSolve)
uniroot.all(BCF.dlmo, c(0.2617994, 6.021386), dlmo_val = dlmo_val)
# [1] 1.886084 2.908276
```

Comment: You can use `uniroot` with the `extendInt="yes"` argument and it will find a zero outside the given initial range by extending the interval. But even that process has its shortcomings.